# Other editors with autocompletion shortcuts similar to those in TeXShop

Tags: editors, texshop, mac

There's one  particular feature I really like about TeXShop. It's the ability to type something like `\bali` + escand you get the entire `\begin{align}` structure or try typing something like `\bite` + esc. It's definitely very convenient.

I know that these things can be done with other editors via keyboard shortcuts, but I don't want to have to memorize a new keyboard shortcut (plus, I already have *many* that I use).

So my question is, is it possible to recreate this with other editors such as vim or TeXStudio?

**Update:** I'm running Mac OSX. To help you help me, I've listed some other mac compatible editors that community users may be familiar with:

- texstudio
- vim with latex suite
- texlipse
- sublime

Comment: See in [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) for “code completion”.

Comment: Give Texmaker a look.  It has some as well.

Answer (score 5):

You could try [TeXnicCenter](http://texniccenter.org/).

It has some autocomplete (by pressing CTRL SPACE) after writing:

*ite*

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item 
\end{itemize}
```

*figu*

```
\begin{figure}%
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{filename}%
\caption{}%
\label{}%
\end{figure}
```

*tabl*

```
\begin{table}%
\begin{tabular}{lcr}

\end{tabular}
\caption{}
\label{}
\end{table}
```

And so many more!  You should really give it a try.

Related posts:

[LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. I forgot to mention I was on osx. But I've upvoted you for your time anyhow.

Answer (score 3):

Well, basically, Emacs shortcuts are similar to whatever you want them to be;).  That said, expanding just `\bali` (and not things like `\bali` + space, `\bali` + tab etc.) might be dangerous; how would you type a control sequence *starting* with `\bali`?

If `\bali` + space is good for you, [Abbrev mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Abbrevs.html) is a ready-made solution you may use.  If you want to have the point (cursor in Emacsspeak) in a particular place in the expanded text (like between the `\begin`...`\end` pair), Abbrev mode is not sufficient; then, you might want to look into [Yasnippet](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet).  In it, you have a way to create snippets of code, expandable either by a keystroke, or by an abbreviation followed by `TAB` (but you can easily change it into `SPACE`, or even a few different and independent keys - though I didn't test these ideas).

Comment: I made the assumption people knew it would be `\bali` + esc. Will using Yasnippet create any conflicts or issues?

Comment: `abbrev`s can also be used without the `abbrev mode` by  triggering the `expand-abbrev` function, and you can bind this to your favorite key (combination).

Comment: @AlanH: well, escape is a strange choice; it is possible, but ESC is used in Emacs as a prefix, so that you may use ESC *and then* x instead of M-x (that is, Alt+x).  But if you bind ESC to expand-abbrev (as alexurba hints), you're fine.  (Well, you have also to remember that abbrevs may use only word-constituent characters, so you'd have to change the syntax class of the backslash).  Put together: I'd rather switch my habit to another keystroke, it's not *that* hard.  But if you really want to have it your way - Emacs will let you.